# Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $α ∈ End(V )$ be a projection. Show that $spec(α) ⊆ \{0, 1\}$. Is the converse true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $α ∈ End(V )$ be a projection. Show that
$spec(α) ⊆ \{0, 1\}$. Is the converse true?

I'm lost on this problem, any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated. The $spec(\alpha)$ is the set of all eigenvalues of $\alpha$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a projection $p$ means $p^2=p$ suppose $u$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $c$, $p(u)=cu$ implies that, $p^2(u)=cp(u)= c^2u$ thus $c^2=c$, $c=0$ or $c=1$.

The converse is not true, for example take a nilpotent endomorphism